# Testing WCF Service with Current Context

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, integration-testing

I am working on unit testing WCF duplex service. Below is part of the code implementing the service interface and the callbackcontract interface. In the test ServiceHost.Open listens to the incoming messages from the client calling EmailRequest method. I need to save the incoming  current context to reply back than do my test assertions. 
Problem I am having is in the test I tried many different ways I cant save the Current Context of the incoming messages to post back to them. It always throws exception for NullRefrence.. It is driving me nuts. How can I save the OperationContext.Current inside the test?

```
[ServiceContract]
Name="Email",
CallbackContract=typeof(IEmailCallbackcontract),
SeeionMode=SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface IEmail
{
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true, Name="Message")]
Void EmailRequest(string request, int MssgID);
}


[ServiceContract(Name="EmaiCallbackcontract")]
public interface IEmailCallbackcontract
{
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true, Name="ResMessage")]
void EmailResponse(string response);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceConextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Email:IEmail
{
public void EmailRequest(string message, int MssgID)
{
IEmailCallbackcontract   callbak=OperationContect.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IEmailCallbackcontract>();
Console.Write("Message Recieved");
callback.EmailResponse("I got the message");
}
}
```

I am NUnit testing

```
[Test]
public void TestEmail()
{
//I create a servicehost based on binding information
Servicehost.Open();
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IEmailCallbackcontract>();
//I want to post message back using OperationContext but keep getting Nullrefrence error 
//for some reason test wont save the Current context of incoming messages. 
}
```

Comment: This is not unit-testing, this is integration testing. Otherwise, just mock the context and only test the specific unit of work, not the back and forth. I won't change the tags as you might disagree, but I would recommend changing this to integration testing.

Comment: While a couple years old, have you taken a look at this article?  [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/06/28/unit-testing-duplex-wcf-services.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/06/28/unit-testing-duplex-wcf-services.aspx)